# Excel defined name does not appears in Hyperlinks defined names

Tags: excel

After I create defined name no mater for which scope

[image]

I do not see this names in hyperlinks defined names

[image]

Why?

Comment: im pretty sure this should be on another SO site as this isnt programming related

Comment: please give a link as I not started another question on others sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to the fact that you used a formula as the Refers to: for the defined name. Defined names that are defined by formulas as considered dynamic and do not show up in lists like hyperlink, defined names, the name bar or GoTo references. There is simply too much calculation cost to keep the lists updated with names based on a formula.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if answered yet. But, if you create the defined name and then link to it PRIOR to declaring the formula, you should should be able to insert the link. Then change the reference to your formula.